# How do we distinguish that "shall" means obligation or future?

Tags: future, obligation

English native speakers, I've seen that the use of shall in first person is usually for future. But consider this John Maynard Keynes' example from 1930 which makes some predictions throughout the text:

"There are changes in other spheres too which we must expect to come. When the accumulation of wealth is no longer of high social importance, there **will be** great changes in the code of morals. **We shall be able to rid** ourselves of many of the pseudo moral principles which have hag-ridden us for two hundred years, by which we have exalted some of the most distasteful of human qualities into the position of the highest virtues. **We shall be able to afford to dare** to assess the money-motive as its true value. The love of money as a possession -as distinguished from the love of money as a means to the enjoyments and realities of life- **will be recognized** for what it is, a somewhat disgusting morbidity..."

My guess:
a) Although "shall" is used with third person plural, I interpret it as a moral  obligation (a cordial way to say "we must").

What do you think? Are these uses of shall future or an obligation?

Comment: Both uses of *shall* are first person.

Comment: OK, sorry I think I elaborated wrong my question. My question is if they are interpreted as an obligation or as future.

Comment: Simple future, I think. Generally, we don't place an obligation on ourselves (or anyone) to be able to do something.

Answer (score 2):

When I was at school, my English teacher taught the use of *shall* and *will*. He would have been at school and university around the time Keynes was writing.

- For simple future, the first person singular and plural use *shall* and others use *will.*
- To indicate obligation or intent, the use is reversed and first-person uses *will* with others using *shall.*

All of Keynes's uses follow this rule and they are all simple future.

Even in the 1980s when this was taught to me, the use of *shall* and *will* was already much much more fluid. I think Mr Miles was attempting, Canute-like, to hold back the tide of liguistic laziness! These days he would say the situation is even worse and can often lead to confusion, but for writing up to the 1930s at least using this rule does generally work for correct interpretation.